# React Native - Unable to use google API - Not supplying enough data to HAL

Tags: react-native, api, google-maps

When trying to use google api (no matter what url/api call) with android emulator I am seeing no feedback from my console when in debug mode.

I opened the logs and saw when I make a call to google the following errors:

```
06-06 20:25:23.709  1745 11272 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:24.707  1752 13025 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 33267084 , only wrote 33129981
06-06 20:25:25.719  1745 11273 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:27.729  1745 11274 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:29.742  1745 11275 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:30.013  1752  7269 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 33130091 , only wrote 33129981
06-06 20:25:31.749  1745 11280 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:33.762  1745 11283 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:35.665  1752 13025 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 33626684 , only wrote 33379178
06-06 20:25:35.780  1745 11284 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:37.533  3899 11285 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-06 20:25:37.533  3899 11285 W android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
06-06 20:25:37.793  1745 11286 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:39.799  1745 11287 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:41.811  1745 11288 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:43.820  1745 11289 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
06-06 20:25:45.832  1745 11290 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
```

It worked just fine the last few months but for with no apparent reason it stopped working and not event throwing errors.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to be related to the emulator. I shut down the emulator and wiped the data in the AVD manager then restarted the emulator and it started working again.